# Where is setImgSrc function defined

Tags: magento-1.7, methods

```
<action method="setImgSrc"><src>images/media/col_left_callout.jpg</src></action>
```

I know this is how we set image in magento using layout xml files. But I tried to locate this function in my magento app. but I was not able to find the function definition.

And i believe there are some more function i tried to locate, but failed

eg: `setImgAlt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well...the method is not defined anywhere.
`setImgSrc($param)` is a 'magic' method. it's equivalent to `setData('img_src', $param)`.
[here is a small explanation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/212646/#t283295) on how it works.

And an [explanation for the general usage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) of `__call()`

Comment: there are six places at least the function setData is defined.in the case of setImgSrc function which function is actually called and how it returns the rendered img tag?

Comment: Most classes in Magento extend `Varien_Object`. That's probably what you are looking for (in the case you presented that one is for sure). But in the general case look in the class ancestors until you find a `getData()` method.

Comment: Thanks. i reached that function earlier itself.but that actually increased my doubts how it produces rendered output. Finally i found out this page callouts/right_col.phtml which solved by doubts. thanks marius